# XPath finder in Sublime

Tags: xpath, sublimetext2

I have read another post on Stackoverflow that talks about this topic, but it was almost all windows based tools. I'm currently running a Mac, and out of all the tools mentioned, http://xpath.alephzarro.com and http://ditchnet.org/aquapath/ was usable in Mac.

Does anyone know of if SublimeText2/3 has a feature that I'm unaware of to find XPath of a certain node? I'm asking about Sublime because I use it as my primary tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found someone who wrote this plugin. Works for SublimeText 2 and 3. Copies XPath to clipboard from where your cursor location.

https://github.com/rosshadden/sublime-xpath

Installation on Mac OSX `Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/<plugin-folder-name>`
Then restart Sublime Text 3.